# What is wrong with this JSON file? Can't be deserialized

Tags: json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have an issue with a JSON file, which is a list of country objects, as below:

```
{
    "Countries": [
        {
            "Code": "AFG",
            "Name": "Afghanistan",
            "Population": 38928346
        },
        {
            "Code": "ALA",
            "Name": "Åland Islands",
            "Population": 28007
        },
        {
            "Code": "ALB",
            "Name": "Albania",
            "Population": 2877797
        },
        {
            "Code": "DZA",
            "Name": "Algeria",
            "Population": 43851044
        },
        {
            "Code": "ASM",
            "Name": "American Samoa",
            "Population": 55191
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use this code to read it and deserialize it into a List object:

```
Stream? countriesResourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Countries.json");

if (countriesResourceStream == null)
{
    return;
}

var countries = new List<Country>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(countriesResourceStream))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    countries = serializer.Deserialize<List<Country>>(new JsonTextReader(reader));
}
```

However the serializer.Deserialize method throws the exception:

> 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Models.EntityFramework.Country]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

What is the issue with my JSON? I have tried both Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json.

Comment: It's not a problem with the JSON per se, except inasfar as it doesn't match the .net data types you're deserializing into.

Comment: It looks like you're telling it that the JSON should be a list of Country objects, but that's not what it is; it's a top-level object with a Country value; _that_ value maps to a list of objects. If you made your JSON file start at the `[` and end at the `]`, the code would presumably work. ("Presumably" because this isn't a [mre] without including the definition of Country, so we can't test our answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON does not represent a list of countries, it represents an object that *contains* a list of countries.  You need another class:

```
class CountryListContainer
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize into the container class and then you can get your country list from that:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(countriesResourceStream))
using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    countries = serializer.Deserialize<CountryListContainer>(jsonReader).Countries;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5DM4il

---

Alternatively, you could change your JSON as @Charles Duffy suggested in the comments.  If the JSON looked like this (without the outer object) then your existing code would work:

```
[
  {
    "Code": "AFG",
    "Name": "Afghanistan",
    "Population": 38928346
  },
  {
    "Code": "ALA",
    "Name": "Åland Islands",
    "Population": 28007
  },
  {
    "Code": "ALB",
    "Name": "Albania",
    "Population": 2877797
  },
  {
    "Code": "DZA",
    "Name": "Algeria",
    "Population": 43851044
  },
  {
    "Code": "ASM",
    "Name": "American Samoa",
    "Population": 55191
  }
]
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMHhcX

Comment: Thank you Brian, you've made my day a little easier now this is working, god knows I need it. I went with the second option, I didn't want a "Countries" object containing a List<Country> but clearly got my wires crossed with the JSON.

Comment: Glad I could help.